# Outbound Packet-Filtering on 3Com 5500G

Tags: acl, 3-com

I have a L3 3Com 5500G, and I'm trying to assign an outbound packet filtering on one GigabitEthernet, however, the only available feature is inbound.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't detail what you have tried, but from what I find in the manual, [3Com SuperStack® 4 Switch 5500G-EI Family
Configuration Guide](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02583472-1.pdf), Chapter 8, ACL Configuration, page 205, **inbound** is the only ACL option:

**packet-filter inbound ip-group** *acl_number* **[ rule** *rule* **[ link-group** *acl_number* **rule** *rule* **] ]** | **link-group** *acl_number* **[ rule** *rule* **] }**

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant; there's no outbound packet filtering. so, to deny access to some host on a router, I need to apply same acl rule to all interfaces including the uplink; however, outbound filtering being used would be applied only on the interface where the host is found. This is something odd I guess that the 5500G does not support outbound filtering. So, my problem isn't resolved.

Comment: You can't do that on this switch. I suppose you could request this feature to be added, but I wouldn't hold my breath. Otherwise, just redesign so that you use inbound filtering. It's probably better to drop the traffic before switching it.

Comment: dropping the packet on the interface before processing switching them is great, yes indeed; however, our network is very wide and complex and many acls are to be applied on each interface. So, the logic handling of the acls and binding them to this great number of interfaces will be time consuming and shall be very accurate and requires conflict revision each time a new acl is applied to an interface. We'll be switching to Catalyst 4500X, but I'm still contemplating about "Why there's no outbound packet filtering on 3Com 5500G!!"

Comment: What is it you want from us? We cannot add a feature to a device which doesn't support that feature. The manufacturer decided, for whatever reason, against implementing that feature. All you can do is ask the manufacturer to add it in a future software release.

Comment: Yikes - out of curiosity I looked this up and it's spelled out in the release notes for 3.0.2 that outbound filtering is just not supported.  That seems pretty limiting.